# Gradle build path in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, build, gradle

I have a Gradle build that I want to be able to run in command line and Eclipse. In the build I have a line like this:

```
String versionNum = new File('version').text
```

which reads the version of the software that is used for build. This works for when I run it in command line, but when I run from under Eclipse it can't find the file. I printed the default path from gradle script under eclipse and it is the path where my eclipse is installed, not where the gradle script is located.

How do I go about that - either changing the default path for build in Eclipse or using the location of the gradle script inside of gradle somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
String versionNum = file('version').text
```

with *file()* being a method on project, which creates a file object relative to the projectdir.

when using *new File()*, a file object will be created in the current working dir

Comment: it's well documented BTW ;-) http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html